# where to add "social_core.backends.yammer.YammerOAuth2" for social authentication in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hey guys I am new to django , I am learning to build some application using it , so  I am following some example instructions of some blog. In that there is need of configuring an `social authentication django` package with my app.
I am not getting where to add this line please point out.

> Add social_django to INSTALLED_APPS Add
>
> social_core.backends.yammer.YammerOAuth2 to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
>
> Set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ‘/badges/’ Set LOGIN_URL = ‘/login/yammer’